# Parse an id and instanciate an associated class

Tags: c++, protocols

Im building a protocol in c++ for a TCP socket communication.
When I catched the id of an incoming packet, I would like to make a generic code that find which known packet (in my protocol) that I received.

```
class NetworkMessage {
public:
    virtual ~NetworkMessage();

    virtual void serialize(NetworkBuffer &buffer) = 0;
    virtual void deserialize(NetworkBuffer &buffer) = 0;

    virtual int32_t getProtocolId() const = 0;
};
```

Example of message

```
class HelloConnectMessage: public NetworkMessage {

public:
    static constexpr int32_t PROTOCOL_ID = 1;

    void serialize(NetworkBuffer &buffer) override;
    void deserialize(NetworkBuffer &buffer) override;
    int32_t getProtocolId() const override;

    int32_t getHelloVar() const;
private:
    int32_t _hellovar;
};
```

I wanted to map the protocolId to the associated child class of NetworkMessage, but we can't hold class types like in Java.
I was about to make something like the following code, that can't compile since it's just an idea of what I really want.

```
std::unordered_map<int, class<? extends NetworkMessage>> messages;
```

My alternative for now, below:

```
static NetworkMessage build_packet(NetworkBuffer &buffer) {
    int32_t id = buffer.readInt();
    switch(id) {
        case HelloConnectMessage::PROTOCOL_ID:
            HelloConnectMessage msg;
            msg.deserialize(buffer);
            return msg;
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid packet");
    }
}
```

But this is not enough generic.. I will waste time rewriting always the same code for each message.. Would appreciate any help, im not familiar to c++

Comment: You need to use (most likely smart) pointers to the base class, and implement virtual class methods. Your container will be a container of (smart) pointers to the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate your map with factory functions. Something like this:

```
template <typename Msg>
std::unique_ptr<NetworkMessage> MakeMessage() { return std::make_unique<Msg>(); }

using Factory_t = std::unique_ptr<NetworkMessage>(*)();

std::unordered_map<int, Factory_t> messages = {
  {HelloConnectMessage::PROTOCOL_ID, MakeMessage<HelloConnectMessage>},
  ...
};

std::unique_ptr<NetworkMessage> build_packet(NetworkBuffer &buffer) {
  ...
  auto msg = messages[id]();
  msg->deserialize(buffer);
  return msg;
}
```

Comment: will messages[id] always make a new instance?

Comment: That was a typo (now fixed). I meant `messages[id]()`. `messages[id]` returns a function pointer - then you call the function, and *that* creates a new message.

Comment: `messages[id]` doesn't. `messages[id]()` does.

Comment: ye that's what I though, nice answer :)

Comment: Do I have to return std::move(msg) instead of msg only? I though we can't copy smart pointers

Comment: I think it should work as-is with a sufficiently modern compiler - there's a special case for `return localVariable;`, allowing the local variable to be moved from. But if it doesn't compile for you, sure, make it `return std::move(msg);`